# Show that if an $n \times n$ matrix, $A$, is nilpotent, then $\text{rank}(A) < n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, nilpotent-groups

A matrix is $A$ is nilpotent if $A^k$ is the $0$ matrix for some $k$.

Show that if an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is nilpotent, then $\text{rank}(A) < n$.

Anyone got any ways to get started on this problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq) to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is nilpotent, then $A^k=0$ for some $k$. Then $\det(A^k) = 0$, but $\det(A^k)=\det(A)^k$. So what can you say about $\det(A)$, and what does that tell you about the rank of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Any nilpotent matrix is similar to an upper triangular matrix with zeros on the diagonal, by a theorem.  Actually it's a special case of the Jordan canonical form.

But such a matrix has $\rm{rank}\lt n$.

Comment: .. with 0's on diagonal.

Comment: @Widawensen right you are.